# Best way to copy Contact name to Nickname & Legal name

Tags: contacts

CiviCRM 4.7.29 / WP 4.9.4

Maybe it's a bit of OCD but I imported about 1000 Organizations and the name imported into Contact name. That left the nickname and legal name fields blank, which drives me nuts. I want them to match the Contact name.

I tried to use Profiles thinking maybe I could specify a variable pointing to each record's Contact name but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Is there a way within Civi to update a large number of records to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: why not just reimport in to those other fields?

Answer (score 1):

This chapter of the user guide should help you: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time_1

Basically you:

1. create a profile with the field you want to view + the ones you want to update
2. Search for the contacts you want to update
3. With the search result actions you select **Batch Update with Profile** and use the profile you created

Comment: In my 2nd paragraph I mentioned that I tried Profiles already. Unless I'm missing something, my understanding is that Profiles allow you to do a one-to-many update. I'm looking for a many-to-many update.

Comment: afaik there is no standard solution then. It would be pretty straightforward to write a small import script or do this with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- putting all these contacts to a CSV,
- open in a spreadsheet and duplicate the name column a few times, then
- reimport in CiviCRM with the "Update" option and a dedupe rule that makes sense, this time specifying nickname and legal name matching. (For example, you could set up a dedupe rule for Internal ID to make it easy to match).

Comment: not sure you need to specifically set up a rule to do so - i think if you import and the import includes Internal ID then it just works

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a way within Civi but I think the easiest way is to do a reimport again, thank you both for the suggestion